# Access element by id with chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, replace

**Description:**

I want to write an Extension which replaces strings in an HTML input Element. So when you click on the popup, it should replace all ' characters with ' .

**Code:**

This is the manifest.json file:

```
{
    "name": "Getting Started Example",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Build an Extension!",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "permissions": ["tabs", "<all_urls>", "activeTab", "storage"],
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
    "manifest_version": 2
}
```

This is the background script:

```
// opens a communication port
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function(port) {

    // listen for every message passing throw it
    port.onMessage.addListener(function(o) {

        // if the message comes from the popup
        if (o.from && o.from === 'popup' && o.start && o.start === 'Y') {

            // inserts a script into your tab content
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {

                // the script will click the button into the tab content
                code: "document.getElementById('header').value =  document.getElementById('header').value.replace(/'/g, '\\\''); console.log(document.getElementById('header').value);"
            });
        }
    });
});
```

The popup.js file:

```
// always waits the document to be loaded when shown
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

    // opens a communication between scripts
    var port = chrome.runtime.connect();

    // listens to the click of the button into the popup content
    document.getElementById('popupBtn').addEventListener('click', function() {

        // sends a message throw the communication port
        port.postMessage({
            'from': 'popup',
            'start': 'Y'
        });
    });
});
```

**Output:**

[image: popup]

Basically you click on the popup, and it calls the popup.js file which sends a message to the background.js file.

The code get's the value of the element with the id 'header', but it isn't replacing the value. When I insert this in the input field:

[image: input]

and i click on the popup it should return this: asdfasdf 'adsfa  ' asdf '

This is what the console logged:

[image: console]

Comment: 1) What do you see in three devtools consoles - the popup, background page, the web page? 2) No need for port/messaging at all because you can invoke executeScript in the popup script. 3) To improve readability consider using `file` parameter instead of `code` so you can write a readable code in the separate file. Or use a template string `\`${() => { your code here }})()\``

Comment: I used the file parameter instead of code and suddenly it worked! Thanks a lot.